# asp.net 2.0 ajax framework throws System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException error when the input string has '\,'

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have this error when using asp.net 2.0 framework.  I have searched online but found no answers, thank you all in advance.  Below is the description.

```
<sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
            <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
                <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
            </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
```

Above is the configuration section in the Web.config. Using the `[AjaxMethod(HttpSessionStateRequirement.ReadWrite)]` attribute to define the ajax method on the server side.  Here is the method: `public virtual AjaxResult Add(string[] values, string[] valueParameters, int editMode)`.  When one `string` of the `string[]` values contains the \, or ,\ , it will fail, the parameter the server got is divided into two part by the ',', if it is 'H\,H', it became to 'H\' and '', if it is 'H,\H' it became to '' and '\H'. And here is the message:

> "{'IsValid':false,'Values':[],'Message':'Index was outside the bounds
>   of the array.','UnformattedMessage':null,'Type':6}"

I have debugged it, the Ajax framework transforms the input string into Json by `'"' + o.replace(/(["\\])/g, '\\$1') + '"'` regex.  For example,

```
"DSF\,DF"
```

will be translated into

```
"DSF\\,DF"
```

I think it is fine but the asp.net framework can't recognize it correctly.

Please help me.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I am using the Ajax.dll 5.6.3.4 and i found there is one version 5.7.22.2. But i can't find the download link, is there anybody can provide me a link, thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you have the right version?
see this... http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/ConfiguringASPNETAJAX.aspx i hope it will help you

Comment: I have compared the two configs, the only difference is the version. In the sample, it uses 1.0.61025.0, our version is 3.5.0.0

Comment: did you try to install SP1? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22

Comment: Yes, I think it's a bug of ajax.dll on analyzing post string.